Azure batch - ResourceContainerAccessDenied
I need help with my azure batch jobs, they are failing with error: ResourceContainerAccessDenied.
I've access issues when running a azure batch towards my storage account. I should add that both are located in same region and subscription.
My batch jobs are supposed to run ffmpeg and fetch and upload the result in my storage account.
I am using Microsoft.Azure.Batch.BatchClient using BatchTokenCredentials. I can create pools, jobs, upload files to store account. But I can't access files in my store account.
I use a Microsoft Entra service principal with Batch.NET (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth)
I've done scenario 1 and configured the virtual network and subnet in my store account, by following instructions in this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/hpc/batch/access-denied-execute-azure-batch-job)
But that didn't help either, I still receive the same error ResourceContainerAccessDenied.
What am I missing?

Can you share the code how you are accessing the file from storage account?

Sure, here it is: https://github.com/Kebne/azure-batch-demo/blob/main/azure-batch-demo/AzureBatch.cs

line 507 failedTasks.Any() is true with error code ResourceContainerAccessDenied
